# Nest - how to do a SpanFirstQuery?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am trying to do a `SpanFirstQuery` with NEST, as described in:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/query-dsl-span-first-query.html

The `SpanFirstQuery` class has a `Match` property, but the `Match` property is an `ISpanQuery` which has a `SpanFirst` property that is a `ISpanFirstQuery`. That seems to be an endless loop.

I am confused..

How to do a spanfirstquery with NEST?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `span_first` query in NEST can be done very simply like this:

```
var s = new SearchDescriptor<ElasticsearchProject>()
    .Query(q => q
        .SpanFirst(sf=>sf
            .MatchTerm(f => f.User, "kimchy")
            .End(3)
        )
    );
```

That will produce the same query as depicted in the official documentation:

```
{
    "span_first" : {
        "match" : {
            "span_term" : { "user" : "kimchy" }
        },
        "end" : 3
    }
}
```